# Amazon SQS did not receive all events after MTurk HIT submissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, mechanicalturk

I have setup the SQS to receive events from MTurk HIT submissions using [SetHITTypeNotification](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_SetHITTypeNotificationOperation.html) API.

There were total 500+ HITs in MTurk. After all HITs were submitted I found only 200+ messages in SQS. What happened to other messages ? Why those were not received in SQS ? The settings of the queue is as follow:

[image]

Comment: As I understand it, AWS makes no guarantees on when SQS messages arrive. Have you checked again to see if there was some delay?

Comment: Is there any chance they expired and got deleted? If you waited more than 14 days to check they would be gone.

Comment: @E.J.Brennan No, it is within the time limit. I am regularly checking the SQS.

Comment: I seem to be having the same issue, although on a smaller scale. @HariDas did you find out what the issue was? How did you solve it?